# How to integrate a download button in shiny apps?

Tags: r, button, shiny, download

I think I have problems with the syntax. It is my first app. And it will need to be re-written. I already have a working function as R.script. But I did not know how to integrate it.
It doesn't download the table. Just some random textfile.
How can I refer to the output$table from the rshiny tool for downloading?
For testing the app you can use any type of files with chronogical numbers with duplicates (e.g. Photo1-1.JPG, Photo2-1.JPG)

````
# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textInput("file_type", "File type", "Enter file type suffix"),
  verbatimTextOutput("file_sign"),
  
  textInput("file_sep", "File separator", "Enter separator"),
  verbatimTextOutput("file_sep"),
  img(src = "logo_ebm.PNG"),
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Katalogisieren von Graphiken"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("files", "File-Upload", multiple = TRUE),
    
    # Button
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      h1("Erstellen eines Graphik-Katalogs"),
      h5("Das Erstellen des Graphiken-Katalogs stellt die Basis für automatisierte Protokolle dar.
          Hierfür wird ein xlsx.file im Zielordner (jener der auch die Graphiken beinhaltet) angelegt.
          Protokolle können im Moment für maximal 4 Bilder erstellt werden."),
      h1("Einspeisen der Graphik-Files"),
      h5("Jeder File-Format ist hier für geeignet (.jpeg,.JPG,.pdf,..). 
         Dieses muss zu Beginn sepezifiziert werden ohne vorangestellten Punkt (z.b ´pdf´).
         keine Unterordner anlegen, es sei denn es ist zwingend erforderlich
         Im nächsten Schritt muss ein Trennzeichen definiert werden, dass Bilder desselben 
         Objekts von seinen dazugehörigen Bildern klar unterscheidet. 
         Zu empfehlen sind Bindestrich (´-´) oder Unterstrich (´_´)."),
      
      # Output: Data file ----
      #textOutput("file_names")
      dataTableOutput('table'),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    )
    
  ))

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  # output$file_sign <- renderText({input$file_type})
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable ({
    # Test if file is selected
    if (!is.null(input$files$datapath)) {
      # Extract file name (additionally remove file extension using sub)
      file_names <- basename(input$files$name)
      sep_sign <- input$file_sep
      # file_type <- paste0(".",input$file_sign)
      file_type <- input$file_sign
      define_pattern <- dput(paste0(sep_sign,"[[:graph:]]","*.",dput(file_type)))
      file_names <- gsub(define_pattern, "", file_names)
      
      library(dplyr)
      schacht <- table(file_names) %>% names()
      repl <- table(file_names) %>% as.numeric()
      docx_filename <- rep(schacht,repl)
      docx_filename %>%  length()
      list.files(pattern= dput(file_type)) %>% length()

      filenames_OG <- list.files(pattern= dput(file_type)) %>% length()

      # DF1 <- table(file_names) %>% as.data.frame()

      docx_filename <- rep(schacht,repl)
      
      final_DF <- data.frame(Index_num = seq_along(docx_filename),
                             Schachtname = docx_filename,
                             jpeg_file = input$files$name,
                             Bildbeschreibung = NA,
                             Ort = NA,
                             Datum = NA,
                             Bearbeiter = NA)
      require(xlsx)
      write.xlsx(final_DF, paste0("Bildregister_",Sys.Date(),".xlsx"), row.names = F, showNA = T)
      return(output$table <- renderDataTable(final_DF))
      } else {
      return(NULL)
      }
    
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")}, 
      content = function(fname){
        write.csv(output$table, fname)}
    )
  })}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`output$table` is not an R dataframe but a rendered DataTable. What you should do is create a reactive that loads in the uploaded files and does the processing and use it for rendering in the `output$table` and within the download handler.
Also the download handler should be outside the `renderDataTable`.

The server will look something like the following:

```
# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
# output$file_sign <- renderText({input$file_type})

read_data <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    req(input$files$datapath)
    
    # assuming below part is correct and reads and gets a dataframe
    
    # Extract file name (additionally remove file extension using sub)
    file_names <- basename(input$files$name)
    sep_sign <- input$file_sep
    # file_type <- paste0(".",input$file_sign)
    file_type <- input$file_sign
    define_pattern <- dput(paste0(sep_sign,"[[:graph:]]","*.",dput(file_type)))
    file_names <- gsub(define_pattern, "", file_names)
    
    library(dplyr)
    schacht <- table(file_names) %>% names()
    repl <- table(file_names) %>% as.numeric()
    docx_filename <- rep(schacht,repl)
    docx_filename %>%  length()
    list.files(pattern= dput(file_type)) %>% length()
    
    filenames_OG <- list.files(pattern= dput(file_type)) %>% length()
    
    # DF1 <- table(file_names) %>% as.data.frame()
    
    docx_filename <- rep(schacht,repl)
    
    final_DF <- data.frame(Index_num = seq_along(docx_filename),
                           Schachtname = docx_filename,
                           jpeg_file = input$files$name,
                           Bildbeschreibung = NA,
                           Ort = NA,
                           Datum = NA,
                           Bearbeiter = NA)
    final_DF
})

output$table <- renderDataTable ({
    DT::datatable(read_data())
})

output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")}, 
    content = function(fname){
        write.csv(read_data(), fname)}
)
}
```

Comment: It still does not download the data.. just random text and it doesn't show my created data after loading it.

Comment: if it's now even showing the created data then there's probably some issue with the data creation part itself. Try setting `browser()` command in the creation part of the code to set up a breakpoint and then debug whether it is actually getting created correctly or not.

Comment: I don't know but can it be that I need to integrate my textfelds into the req function?

Comment: I never tried browser() before I tried it but it does show me anything. Also there are no warnings or error after running the app

Comment: browser will set up a breakpoint so that app will stop once it reaches that statement. Your shiny app will be "paused", and you will have access to Rstudio console, where you can run commands one by one and test out different stuff. You can get more info about this [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html#browser)